# How to link Wordpress heartbeat to ajax form

Tags: ajax, jquery, forms, front-end, heartbeat-api

I have a form that `$_POST`s an input value, and user's ID that saves the data to the database:

```
// frontend form 
<form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="location" id="name1" value="1">
    <label for="name1">Label 1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="location" id="name2" value="2">
    <label for="name2">Label 2</label>

    <input type="radio" name="location" id="name3" value="3">
    <label for="name3">Label 3</label>

    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{userid}">
</form>     


// footer script
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#form" ).change(function(a) {
        a.preventDefault();
        var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);

        $.ajax({
            method:         "POST",
            data:           formdata,
            contentType:    false,
            processData:    false
        });
    });
});
</script>


// validation snippet
<?php
    $location = isset( $_POST['location'] ) ? $_POST['location'] : '';
    $userID   = isset( $_POST['userid']   ) ? $_POST['userid']   : '';
    update_user_meta( $userID, 'location_current',  $location );
?>
```

When the users sets the radio location from their desktop, it send the form to the server, and saves it.

Each user also has a display (tablet) that has no `input` but echoes out the location value.

I currently have the tablet refreshing every 5 minutes, but wanted it to be more of a push with WP heartbeat.

I tried using this example: https://gist.github.com/strangerstudios/5888123

But wasnt sure how to have the value of the `data['client'] = 'marco';` be `data['client'] = '<?= $_POST['location']; ?>';` each time as it is printed once and not refreshed once the page is loaded or the location changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Saving data**

Based on [Heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/), you can add custom data to the sent heartbeat on `heartbeat-send` event in js. This would be used instead of the ajax function you have in your code example.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'heartbeat-send', function ( event, data ) {
  // Grab the required form data
  data.location = jQuery('input[name="location"]:checked').val();
  data.userid = jQuery('input[name="userid"]').val();
});
```

You can then use the data in PHP with [`hearbeat_recieved`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/heartbeat_received/) filter. There's also the [`heartbeat_nopriv_received`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/heartbeat_nopriv_received/) filter for no-privilege environments.

```
add_filter( 'heartbeat_received', 'myplugin_save_location_on_heartbeat', 10, 2 );
function myplugin_save_location_on_heartbeat( $response, $data ) {
  // data required
  if ( empty( $data['location'] ) || empty( $data['userid'] ) ) {
    return $response;
  }
  // validate
  if ( ! is_numeric( $data['location'] ) || ! is_numeric( $data['userid'] ) ) {
    return $response;
  }
  // sanitize
  $location = absint( $data['location'] );
  $userID = absint( $data['userid'] );
  // update
  update_user_meta( $userID, 'location_current',  $location );
  // optional response
  $send_data_back = true;
  if ( $send_data_back ) {
    $response['location'] = $location;
    $response['userid'] = $userID;
  }
  // send response
  return $response;
}
```

You can access the data (response from `hearbeat_recieved`) again on `heartbeat-tick` event in js,

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'heartbeat-tick', function ( event, data ) {
  // Check for our data, and use it.
  if ( ! data.location || ! data.userid ) {
    return;
  }
  // use the response as needed
  console.log("location: " + data.location);
  console.log("user: " + data.userid);
});
```

**Get data**

With couple of tweaks you can get just the location data instead of saving it.

First send user id with `heartbeat-send` in js,

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'heartbeat-send', function ( event, data ) {
  data.userid = jQuery('input[name="userid"]').val();
});
```

Then respond with current location user meta in PHP on `hearbeat_recieved`,

```
add_filter( 'heartbeat_received', 'myplugin_get_location_on_heartbeat', 10, 2 );
function myplugin_get_location_on_heartbeat( $response, $data ) {
  // data required
  if ( empty( $data['userid'] ) ) {
    return $response;
  }
  // validate
  if ( ! is_numeric( $data['userid'] ) ) {
    return $response;
  }
  // sanitize
  $userID = absint( $data['userid'] );
  // update
  $location = get_user_meta( $userID, 'location_current',  true );
  // send response
  return $response['location'] = $location;
}
```

**EDIT 1:** I think you could also use [`get_current_user_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/) inside the php response function to get the user id, if you don't want to or can't send it in js on `heartbeat-send` event.

Last, update your view with the recieved data on `heartbeat-tick` in js,

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'heartbeat-tick', function ( event, data ) {
  // Check for our data, and use it.
  if ( ! data.location ) {
    return;
  }
  // if using radio buttons
  jQuery('input[name="location"][value='"+data.location+"']').prop('checked', true);
  // if you want to show result in somewhere else
  jQuery('#location-output-element').text(data.location);
});
```

I hope this helps and answers your question.

Comment: thanks for that! I was wondering, testing this out when two browsers are open they are both overriding each other. if I have a function that detects mobile devices, where would I put this condition to stop mobile devices from sending, but only receiving?

Comment: If you're using for example PHP `Mobile_Detect` class / library to detect mobile devices, then you would add the mobile check as the first thing to the `heartbeat_received` callback function. This way server would refuse save requests on mobile. Or if you check for mobile devices on front end with js, then add the check to `heartbeat-send` event function. Third way is to wrap the `update_user_meta` in a if-else statement, where on `true` (is mobile) only `get_user_meta` is used and on `false` (not mobile) user meta is updated.

Answer (score 0):

To send value using HTTP methods, the page must submit data. Only page refresh will not work. Your page must send a post request with the data location and you are using ajax to send form data.

In the API `data['client'] = 'marco';` you can use your own data object send from your ajax request.

```
data['client'] = your formdata;
```

or you can use your PHP code same as you mentioned above:

```
data['client'] = '<?php echo $_POST['location']; ?>'; // make sure you validate data first.
```

If this doesn't help, please show the full implementation of API and usage of your ajax data.